# Overwrite restricted application file?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to manually patch my application. The application makes use of a Service which i make sure to stop and uninstall prior to attempting any overwriting of the application dll's.

The issue is that i can't overwrite, or even delete some of the dll files which are the core of the application, these dll files are used by the service i uninstalled first.

I use the following method to pass in the new file-path in order to replace the old DLL which is located inside the root directory of the application in `C:\Program Files\AppName\`

> public static bool CopyFile(string newFile, string oldFile)
>       {
>
> ```
>     var newfile = new FileInfo(newFile);
>     var oldfile = new FileInfo(oldFile);
>
>     var f2 = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, oldFile);
>     f2.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write | FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, newFile);
>
>     try
>     {
>         f2.Demand();
>     }
>     catch (SecurityException s)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine(s.Message);
>     }
>
>
>        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
>        {
>             try
>             {
>                File.Delete(oldfile.FullName);
>                newfile.CopyTo(oldfile.FullName, true);
>                return true;
>             }
>             catch
>             {
>                 Thread.Sleep(200);
>             }
>        }
>        return false;
> }
> ```

I just wish to provide a new file and remove the old one, replace it, overwrite it.... The application

Note: The application i run to do the patching runs as administrator.

Any idea?

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Do you mean the DLL is still locked in place, although the service itself is stopped and uninstalled? Who else has a handle on this DLL? To find out, use SysInternal's Handle utility: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by making use of a "middle man" in other words, another application which downloads another executable and passes command line arguments to it.

Originally, my service would download an executable (call it `Installer.exe`). `Installer.exe` would then attempt to stop the service and patch the content, this did not work.

I now have the service running, it downloads "`Installer.exe`".

`Installer.exe` will load up and download `PatchPayload.exe`.

`PatchPayload.exe` runs and kills off the Service, uninstalls it and then download all required patch content from a centralized server and patch the service core files individually then install the service and run it again.